# KVM host and guest cannot communicate, other traffic works fine

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, linux-kvm, bridging

I have a KVM host and a guest on it.

The KVM host hosts a mail service (postfix). The VM is a spam filter (called "spamfilter" for ease).

The basic problem and question is that spamfilter (KVM Guest) and postfix on KVM Host) cannot communicate.
tcpdump shows that tcp handshake SYN is sent from KVM Guest over VLAN to network via Router-on-a-stick and arrives at the destined KVM Host interface. However, the KVM Host does not answer. Same is true for ICMP.

So apparently packets from KVM Guest to are dropped somewhere on the KVM host. Why?

---

#### Details and troubleshooting, for who dares reading:

Network layout:

This is a Gentoo Linux with a single physical network adapter enp2s0 and the VM network is configured with a bridge **br203**

The KVM host, with the mail service, is configured with **br201**.

Bridges **br203** and **br201** are configured with VLAN IDs **203** and **201** respectively. Both have 192.168.20x.254 addresses.
Both are on a VLAN trunk that in turn is connected to a separate firewall and both do communicate over that firewall (as a packet capture on the firewall confirms).

The traffic flow would be:

**KVM host > interface (br201) > VLAN201 > firewall > VLAN203 > br203 > spamfilter KVM Guest**

and vice versa:

**spamfilter KVM Guest > br203 > VLAN203 > firewall > VLAN201 > (br201) interface > KVM host**

`ifconfig` would show (skipping stats line, there are no drops, overruns..., sorting output):

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 52464  bytes 29573045 (28.2 MiB)

enp2s0.200: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.200.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

enp2s0.201: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

br201: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.201.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.201.255
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

enp2s0.203: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

br203: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.203.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.203.255
        ether d4:3d:7e:4f:0c:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fe:54:00:ef:66:9a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

A Ping command to ping from KVM hosts' address 192.168.201.254 to 192.168.203.254: `ping -I br201 192.168.203.254`
tcpdump output for one ICMP request and reply:

```
request:
14:55:54.829736 br201 Out IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829740 enp2s0.201 Out IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829742 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829990 enp2s0 P  IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829990 enp2s0.203 P  IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829998 vnet0 Out IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.829990 br203 P  IP 192.168.201.254 > 192.168.203.254: ICMP echo request, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
reply:
14:55:54.830218 vnet0 P  IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830226 enp2s0.203 Out IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830229 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830218 br203 P  IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830368 enp2s0 P  IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830368 enp2s0.201 P  IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
14:55:54.830368 br201 In  IP 192.168.203.254 > 192.168.201.254: ICMP echo reply, id 13614, seq 1, length 64
```

---

Based on that, it seems to me that packets are dropped "between" br201 and the application that is to receive them. That seems to only occur when traffic originates from an address in the KVM Hosts routing table.

Comment: This is the right forum, but is there any way to trim this down? This seems to need more focus.

Comment: This question may do better on server fault (as KVM & VLAN are usually business technologies), Linux, or network

Comment: Why does the spamfilter VM seem to have the IP `192.168.203.254`?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Sorry, the question itself is rather simple; the troubleshooting I had done and layout might be more complex. Tried with formatting to get things in order, but I will try to re-order and remove.

Comment: @Tom Yan - The spamfilter is the KVM guest with that IP as br203 IP and can be reached with it from the network outside the KVM Host.

Comment: @TomYan Nice cleanup! I retracted my close vote.

Comment: @boro `with that IP as br203 IP` So you are confirming that it does have the IP of `192.168.203.254`, right? The problem is, why do you have it configured so? It pretty much makes no sense. (Imagine you have two hosts in the same LAN with the same IP.)

Comment: Btw, I believe that it's normal that a (Linux) host will ignore traffics with source IP that is one of its own IPs but is not coming in from `lo`. Linux does not track traffics to make sure the communication to be symmetrical, so not ignoring the traffics will cause it to route replies to itself (because of the local routes). I guess that might be sort of a security concern, and either way, it won't work in the way you expected, at least not without some quirky mangling.

Comment: @TomYan The 192.168.203.254 is a unique address, why? The bridge br203 has this IP and forwards to the VM; they're not seen as duplicate. The idea was different VMs and services running with each unique IP.
VM1 with postfix was on 201 subnet (VM1 not existing anymore, since postfix now running on hardware
VM2 with postfix was on 202 subnet
VM3 with spam filter serving the two postfix'
VM4-6 with other purpose but similar 204-206 subnets.

Comment: @boro `The bridge br203 has this IP and forwards to the VM` Unless I've (persistently) misunderstood what you mean, you probably have some misunderstanding on how things work with bridged setup. You don't need to, and you shouldn't, configure the IP you want for a VM on the bridge it is attached to. As I said, you literally have two hosts here, the VM host and the VM. Under no typical circumstances you should use one same IP for two hosts. (Besides, your question is in particular about host-guest communication. Why would you expect any of them to know "who is who" when you use the same IP?)

Comment: I'm not sure where you see the two IPs; br203 has that .203.254. I searched some how-to to describe it better:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm
translating from that link: br0 = br203, enp0s29u1u1 = enp2s0.203 (VLAN203 on enp2s0).
Keep in mind that traffic outside KVM host <> VM works perfectly fine.

Was thinking that br201 is pointless since I have no VM attached to it
spamfilter KVM Guest > br203 > VLAN203 > firewall > VLAN201 interface (and IP) > KVM host
To me, traffic is dropped on enp2s0.201, as the tcpdump on the ping command shows.

Comment: What two IPs? I was asking for confirmation on a simple matter: are both br203 (the VM host) and the spamfilter VM configured with the same IP (`192.168.203.254`). It's literally a yes no question, which you can check the answer with `ifconfig` (or better, `ip a`) on both the host and the guest, in case you are somehow not sure. And it's a wrong / non-sensical thing to do, so if it's the case, stop using IPs you use for your host bridges for your VMs at the same time. (Or, in other words, could you clarify on what IP does your spamfilter VM has?)

Comment: That will be misunderstanding on my side; all br20x have the respective 20x.254 addresses and the VMs inside share the 20x.254 IP (so yes that would be duplicate).

This is a new server migrated from another one with the same OS (Gentoo) and hypervisor layout (copied configurations); it had 6 VMs with the exact same configuration. That problem described above might have always been there, I just never consciously attempted to do host<>guest communication.
Guest<>network had always worked.
Why does the ping get sent fine from the br203, but gets dropped at the new enp2s0.201 (former br201)?

Comment: See [this comment above](https://superuser.com/questions/1818231/kvm-host-and-guest-cannot-communicate-other-traffic-works-fine?noredirect=1#comment2860766_1818231) which I left much earlier. (By `route replies to itself (because of the local routes)` I mean like in a loopback manner, i.e., not going to your firewall / router.)